# How to get multiline text notification using pares in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push-notification, multiline

I made sample project for parse push notification and working right now, and got the push notification but issue is multiline text not coming and single line dot.... shown notification, So android guys what i do???
Help me
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *So android guys what i do???* ...read the doc... 1. dissable the default "pares" notification 2. catch the push message 3. build own notification using newer/compat api ... how to do this? using google ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`setStyle()`](https://parse.com/) method while you are building a long notification.

### Edit

Ok I realised only now that you are trying to do it with [**Parse.com**](https://parse.com/), unfortunately you can not do it.

> According to Parse, you have to **write a custom notification receiver**
>   in order to do this.

So the only way to archive it is to write your own custom notification receiver and and buil a notification as you want it to be.

Comment: thanks for reply.. But parse code implement and i do not handle notification class using it.